# как лучше хранить данные для recyclerview в котором cardview?

Tags: android, база-данных, recyclerview, cardview

дайте совет, в этот макет пользователь добавляет cardview загружая с сервера первый раз.
вопрос: как лучше их сохранить локально что бы в следующий раз список взял данные локально и создался без подключения к интернету ? спс[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохраните список в базу данных. Можно использовать [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

Флоу может быть примерно такой:

- У вас есть репозиторий который отвечает за данные которые вы будете получать. В нем есть метод типа `getData()`
- Этот метод по дефолту идет в базу данных:

  - если там данные актуальные (вы можете тут прикрутить какую-то проверку, например по времени) то он отдает их из БД.
  - если данных нет или они не актуальны то репозиторий идет в сеть, когда он получает данные он по пути сохраняет их в БД и отдает эти данные дальше в ваш адаптер.

Comment: Спасибо большое!